# How to get the value in the odata.nextlink (json file) in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, odata

This should be super simple but I can't seem to figure it out.  I need syntax to grab the value of the odata.nextlink from the json file to use to grab the next set of data.  Using PHP/Curl.  I have tried several syntax and just can't get it right.  Right now I am trying to use $url = @odata.nextlink;

Tried several different formats to set the odata.nextlink to a variable so I can use it on my next dataset pull.

```
//code for original pull 
$url = 'https://...?$filter=$top=5000&$skip=5000&$Select=field1,field2,field3';

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'Content-Type: application/json', 
  'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip',
   'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
   ));

....

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

//code trying to grab odata.nextlink, I have tried various methods.  This is the line I need help with. 
$url = @odata.nextlink;

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'Content-Type: application/json', 
  'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip',
   'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
   ));

....

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

json file odata.nextlink:
"@odata.nextLink":"https://...?$filter=$top=5000&$skip=15000&$Select=field1, field2, field3"}
```

Its not pulling the second set of data that is using the nextlink value.

Comment: do `var_dump($data)` and display none sensitive ouput here.

Comment: not really too familar with odata, but have you tried $array = json_decode()  on the results, and then $array['@odata.nextLink'] ?

Comment: I will try the $array= json_decode... and I will do the var_dump and add the output.

Comment: Still trying to solve this... The var_dump($data) displays: bool(true),   I am still trying to figure it out using the json_decode() with the array but not having much luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonb=json_decode($yourjson,true);

echo $jsonb['@odata.nextLink'];
```